# How do I adjust the arguments of the Hartigans Dip Test in R to fit my specific data?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, bimodal

I want to test my data (a distribution of saccade-amplitudes, N = 25092) for unimodality with the Hartigans Dip Test, more specific the dip.test() function in the diptest-package in R. A paper I read by Mergenthaler & Engbert (2010) used the Hartigans Dip Test for the exact same purpose, but they only gave the following information: *"The bimodality was statistically significant based on Hartigans dip-test (sample = 5000, resulting P < 10^-8)"*.

Because I am not an expert at statistics (actually quite far from it), I am very unsure about how to choose the arguments for the dip.test-function. The default is `dip.test(x, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)`, which means the p-value is computed via linear interpolation. I do not know what B refers to in this case. I could also compute the p-value via a Monte Carlo Simulation (simulate.p.value = TRUE), in this case B would indicate the number of replicates used in the Monte Carlo test.

What I essentially wanna know is if I should let the dip.test compute the p-value via linear interpolation or via Monte Carlo Simulation and which value I should choose for B, considering my pretty large sample size. I am also really interested in how you'd explain why you would choose the one or the other.

I tried both options, computing my p-value via the default (simulate p.value =FALSE, B = 200) and one via Monte Carlo Simulation with B = 7500 replicates (because of a paper specifying that that's the number of replicates that produces robust results with the least amount of computing power needed). Both gave me the exact same results: D = 0.022962, p-value < 2.2e-16, so I know my distribution is at least bimodal and the null hypothesis can be rejected.

Still, I really wanna know how to correctly apply the hartigans dip test to my data, respectively how to choose my arguments.

This is my first time asking a question on here, so I am sorry in advance if it's not exactly appropriate for this community or the way I am asking the question is mildly confusing.

Thank you in advance!